# How to display location on map when i click on button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have that code for a field text, button and map:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" onclick="get_location(this)"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <input type="text" name="et_full_location" id="et_full_location" class="text-field input-item required" placeholder="<?php _e("Enter your place's address", ET_DOMAIN); ?>" />
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="et_location_lat" id="et_location_lat" class="text-field input-item " />
<input type="hidden" name="et_location_lng" id="et_location_lng" class="text-field input-item " />
<style type="text/css">#map{height:200px !important;width:95%!important;margin-top:10px!important;}</style>
<div id="map" style=""></div>
<span style=" font-size: 0.8em; font-style: italic;"><?php _e("Drag the marker to specify correct coords.", ET_DOMAIN); ?></span>
```

My map code display like that:

[image]

If i type in that field location, my map display the location what i type and that is ok, but when i try to click on GeoLocation icon from left, my function put location in field but the map doesn't work (Doesn't display my location). My map work always if i type not when i press the button. How can i do?

My function for location is that:

```
<?php
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));

        $country = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));

        $address =  $details->city . " " . $country->region;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function get_location(element)
    {
        document.getElementById('et_full_location').value = "<?php echo $address; ?>";
    }    

</script>
```

Comment: If the `et_full_location` input is set as a `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` input. Instead of setting the input's value try calling `autocomplete.set("place", place)` to set the place programatically.

Comment: Where can i "put autocomplete.set("place", place)" in my code?